# Corrupt file after Python Requests download

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, download, python-requests, writefile

After downloading xlsx file via requests, when trying to open it I get error in excel saying **file cannot be open, it is corrupt**. I think this has something to do with encoding and apparent_encoding in the reqsponce. See image below, and notice the format of **content**.
[Responce - corrupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUTep.png)
But this is just my guess. My code works well for another download from the same web, and there responce looks like this: 
[Responce - not corrupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnkq8.png)

This is my code:

```
resp1 = requests.get(url_full, headers=task, verify=False)



#file_name = resp1.json()['fileName']
file_name = pack + '-' + date_str + '.xlsx'
with open(path + file_name, 'wb') as f:
        #for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            #shutil.copyfileobj(BytesIO(resp.content), f)
        f.write(resp1.content)
f.close()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you download the first file using e.g. `curl`, or your browser, does it end up corrupt or correct?

Comment: @9000 It works via browser, and the url I got exactly from the browser.

Comment: responce headers are ```{'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true' ...........'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Date': 'Fri, 07 Feb 2020 22:46:55 GMT'}```

Answer (score 1):

The Requests [docs suggest using `iter_content`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) for chunked responses.

You had it in your code, but for some reason you tried to write each chunk to a separate file.
Consider:

```py
# Note the added `stream=True`.
response = requests.get(url_full, headers=task, verify=False, stream=True)

with open(whatever_path, "wb") as outfile:
  for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=None):  # Let the server decide.
    outfile.write(chunk)
# Here the response is exhausted, and outfile is closed.
```

Comment: I've tried above myself.  The only variation I had to make was the request was a POST that provides some data and the response returns the downloaded file.  I still receive an error trying to open in Excel that the file is corrupted.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user987654321: Try storing a copy of the file you send from your server code somewhere on the server. Then copy it from the server with something you know works correctly (like scp or whatever remote access you use), and see if it's corrupted. If not, then the problem is in the transmission.