# Python-download excel (xlsx) file from sharepoint to my local drive is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, python-requests

I am trying to download the xlsx file which is in company sharepoint to my local drive to process it furthur using pandas.
Though the connection to the sharpoint gives me Response[200], test.xlsx in my local drive is corrupted and I am not able to open it.

```
import requests

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
file = "company sharepoint .xlsx"
username = 'myUsername'
password = 'myPassword'

resp=requests.get(file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
print(resp)

output = open('test.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

Comment: I would check out the Office365 SDK for Python. https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60117783/5320906)